# Elasticsearch query prefer exact match over partial match on multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I am doing a free text search on documents with multiple fields. When I perform a search I want the documents that have a perfect match on any of the labels to have a higher scoring. Is there any way I can do this from the query?

For example the documents have two fields called `label-a` and `label-b` and when I perform the following multi-match query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "apple",
            "type": "most_fields",
            "fields": [
              "label-a",
              "label-b"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following results (only the relevant part):

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "salad",
    "_type": "fruit",
    "_id": "4",
    "_score": 0.581694,
    "_source": {
      "label-a": "apple pie and pizza",
      "label-b": "pineapple with apple juice"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "salad",
    "_type": "fruit",
    "_id": "2",
    "_score": 0.1519148,
    "_source": {
      "label-a": "grape",
      "label-b": "apple"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "salad",
    "_type": "fruit",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 0.038978107,
    "_source": {
      "label-a": "apple apple apple apple apple apple apple apple apple apple apple apple",
      "label-b": "raspberry"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "salad",
    "_type": "fruit",
    "_id": "3",
    "_score": 0.02250402,
    "_source": {
      "label-a": "apple pie and pizza",
      "label-b": "raspberry"
    }
  }
]
```

I want the second document, the one with the value `grape` for `label-a` and value `apple` for `label-b`, to have the highest score as I am searching for the value *apple* and one of the labels has that exact value. This should work regardless of which label the exact term appears.

Answer (score 0):

Because Elasticsearch uses tf/idf model for scoring you are getting these results. Try to specify in your index fields "label-a" and "label-b" additionally as not-analyzed(raw) fields. Then rewrite your query someth like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": {
             "match": {
                 "label-a.raw": {
                     "query": "apple",
                      "boost": 2
                        }
                    }
                },
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "apple",
            "type": "most_fields",
            "fields": [
              "label-a",
              "label-b"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The should clause will boost documents with exact match and you will probably get them in the first place. Try to play with the boost number and pls check th equery before running. This is just and idea what you can do

Comment: Thank you for the idea! Looks nice. I don't want to change the mapping of the index though.